# How to view two objects with different color sources in the same viewport shading?

Tags: rendering, materials, shaders, vertex-colors

I am quite new to blender and I'm having trouble rendering the following environment. I have a car in that has been created in blender and has been appended to the project, and the background house, which is a .blg file that contains a 3d mesh / point cloud but the color of this building can only be seen if you set the viewport shading light to flat and the color to attribute. Is there a way to show both the car and the building with their real colors, so kind of fuse both images below? and be able to render the result with correct lighting if that makes sense.

[image]
Viewport shading: Solid display mode. Where only the building has color.

[image]
Viewport shading: Material Preview mode. Where only the car has color.

[image]
Settings to view the color of the building.

[image]
Render preview, but with no colored building.

EDIT 1: Added image of color attribute and attribute of the building

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the objects have different sources for their color, the *Solid*  Viewport shading won't be useful here. You either need to use *Material Preview* or *Rendered* Viewport shading. Additionally, you need to set the material of the building to use the corresponding color attribute that shows up in the *Solid* Viewport shading. The steps are listed below:

1. Figure out the name of the attribute. This will typically show up under *Object Data Properties > Color Attributes*.

[image: Color]

2. Connected the *Color* output of an *Attribute* node to the *Material Output* node directly or through a BSDF (shader). A direct connection won't produce shading which is the correct option here as the shading and shadows seem to be baked into the attribute.
3. Set the name of the attribute in the *Name* field of the *Attribute* node.

[image: Shader]

---

**Update:** Steps 2 and 3 are shown in the GIF below. The steps are carried out in the *Shading* workspace. We already know the color attribute is called *Col*.

[image: Steps]

Comment: I have added my building attributes to the original post, I have a color attribute and an attribute with the of 'Col', but i dont know how to do step 2 of what you mentioned, my knowledge in blender is quite limited atm.

Comment: That means the building's color attribute is called *Col* in your case (not *Color*). I will add a GIF showing how to carry out the remaining steps.

Comment: Thank you very much, the GIF is perfect!

Comment: You're welcome!