# Display Vertex color and textures in viewport solid view?

Tags: 3d-view

I like using an image plain for my reference, but I'm also working on a model that has vertex color and atm using texture only displays the plane, and attribute only the vertex color. Any good work arounds?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you check [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308202/how-to-view-two-objects-with-different-color-sources-in-the-same-viewport-shadin/308208)? I think it's very similar to yours.